# Scheme -- how to find the intersection of two streams

Tags: stream, scheme, racket

Is there a way to define a stream as the intersection of two streams? i.e., if a and b are streams, c is the stream containing the elements that are in both a and b.

Comment: Are the streams infinite? are they sorted? What have you tried so far? please post the code you've written as part of the question

Comment: Don't cross the streams!

Comment: Also you could try comparing lists and treat them as if they were sets. Making then an intersection function. Try [stream->list](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html?q=stream&q=string%3C&q=class#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-~3elist%29%29)

Answer (score 2):

Two streams can be intersected as long as they're sorted (even if they're infinite!). Granted, if they're infinite and not sorted there's no way to know if an element is in a stream. But if they're sorted we can advance over either stream (depending on the element's order) until we find an element in common, which is then added to the output.

Here's a proof of concept using Racket's stream primitives, and assuming two streams of numbers as input:

```
(define (stream-intersection s1 s2)
  (if (or (stream-empty? s1) (stream-empty? s2))
      (stream)
      (let ((x1 (stream-first s1))
            (x2 (stream-first s2)))
        (cond ((> x1 x2)
               (stream-intersection s1 (stream-rest s2)))
              ((< x1 x2)
               (stream-intersection (stream-rest s1) s2))
              (else
               (stream-cons x1
                            (stream-intersection (stream-rest s1)
                                                 (stream-rest s2))))))))
```